# Mpich2 - hydra_pmi_proxy: error while loading libraries: libcr.so.0

Tags: linux, mpich

I am trying to connect multiple virutalbox linux systems with mpich2.
What i allready did:

1. Install mpich-3.1.4
2. Copy public key to every node
3. install nfs server on every node.
4. test if shared map works ( it does)
5. added paths on Master

   export PATH=/share/mpich2/bin:$PATH
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/mirror/mpich2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

i also aded this to: ./bashrc

6. install build-essential

But at the end when i want to start program (mpiexec -f hosts -n 4 ./mpi_test
), i get error:

**hydra_pmi_proxy: error while loading libraries: libcr.so.0:cannot open shared object file: No souch file or directory**

Comment: `libcr.so.o` is a rather unlikely filename. If you have it mentioned in your makefile, try changing to `libcr.so.0`. If your error message in fact says `libcr.so.0`, you need to install a package that has this file.

Comment: @n.m. Sory it is 0

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `http://jahanzebnotes.blogspot.com/2013/07/hydrapmiproxy-error-while-loading.html`

If you encounter this error while running mpich, then install this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcr-dev
```

If you are still facing this problem then you might not have configured your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` correctly, then go to `~/.bashrc`, you will see this line at the start of your bash:
`[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`

Put your `LD_LIBRRAY_PATH` and `PATH` variable exports before this line.